# Как лучше сказать?

Tags: семантика, лексика

"Пешая прогулка" или "пешеходная прогулка" (в программе туристического маршрута). Есть ли хоть какая-нибудь разница в значении этих двух слов. Может, какие-то семантические оттенки?

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос. Попробую в порядке обсуждния, так сказать.
Формально пеший и пешеходный - паронимы, синонимичны как раз в рассматриваемом значении. Т.е. оба варианта одинаково допустимы. Но это не исключает небольших стилистических (не смысловых) различий. Ко всему прочему есть ещё тонкий момент, связанный с различием значений "туристический" и "туристский".

Не могу сосласться на авторитетов, но я бы рассматривал два варината. *Пеший туристический маршрут* и *пешеходная туристская прогулка*. Давайте исходить вот из чего. Туризм (а "туристический" образовано от "туризм") бывает именно пешим, не пешеходным. Поэтому, *если прогулка туристическая, то пешая*.  
Обратно, "туристский" - от "турист", а "турист-пешеход" точнее чем "пеший турист", т.к. "пешеходный" отноится к человеку, а пеший - к чему угодно. Т.е. *если пешеходная, то туристская*.
Осталась понять, к чему относится сама прогулка. К "туристу" или к "туризму". И тут мне кажется, что *маршрут* может относиться и к туризму, и к туристам, но в данном контексте скорее всё-таки к туризму, т.е. *маршрут - туристический*. А вот прогулка - явно к человеку, т.е. *прогулка - туристская*, а следовательно - *пешеходная*.
Итак. Моя рекомендация: **пешеходная туристская прогулка**. Хотя по фонетичеким соображениям этот вариант явно проигрывает **пешей туристической прогулке**. Поэтому, если абсолютная стилистичекая точность не требуется, готов согласиться и на последний вариант.